# How to parse 10 digit phone number into Integer in Java

Tags: java, string, integer

I have to do a validation where it is mentioned that phone number should be 10 digits like 9867610012 and if its true I have to set its value in a setter method whose argument is an Integer and I can't change it's argument. As we know, Integer has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). When I parse the String to Integer using Integer.parseInt("9867610012"), I am getting following exception at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9867610012".
```

Can you suggest some way where I can set a 10 digit String to Integer.

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: Use `Long.parseLong()`

Comment: Thats a very bad idea btw. A phone number should never be an Integer. If you have a 0 as prefix (which is very common) it will just be removed. An international number starts with something like 0049123123 ... parsing that into an integer will give you a broken number

Comment: Don't fall into the trap to think a phone number can be represented as an int or long. It is a string of digits, not a number. Remember, phone numbers can start with 0.

Comment: Why? Phone numbers aren't integers. You should treat them as indicitave data, not as values.

Comment: @Henry remember phone numbers can start with *`+`*.

Comment: And can contain `(` and `)`, and spaces.

Comment: I think we're all trying to say that you have an XY Problem. Trying to solve one way, when in fact, the solution is entirely different

Comment: you should leave it as a string and use regex to test if it's valid (whatever is valid for you).

Comment: You should take a look at libphonenumber from Google, imho

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, You should leave it as a `String` and then validate using [`regex`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html). 
In Your situation I'll give an example (10 digits, may start with zero). Don't assume that my code will be perfect - it's just to give you an idea.

```
boolean isValid = false;
do {
   Scanner phoneSc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String phone = phoneSc.next();
   isValid = isPhoneValid(phone);
} while (!isValid);


public boolean isPhoneValid(String phone) {
    String regex = "\\d{10}"; //regex for 10 digits
    return phone.matches(regex);
}
```

If You don't know regex, learn them. They are very useful. If You don't want to learn, web is full of [examples](https://www.journaldev.com/641/regular-expression-phone-number-validation-in-java). You can add to regex possible `+` in front, `(` and `)`, maybe some dashes `-` cause some numbers have it. Regexes are perfect for such task.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseLong()`.

> **public static long parseLong(String s)**
>                         **throws NumberFormatException**
>
> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal long. The characters in the string must
>   all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII
>   minus sign '-' (\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus
>   sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.
>
> **Parameters:** s - a String containing the long representation to be
>   parsed
>
> **Returns:** the long represented by the argument in decimal.
>
> **Throws:** NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a
>   parsable long.

And since `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`, it can serve your purpose. So instead of `Integer` use `Long`.

**Note to OP :** as many have pointed out, you may need to review your code logic to consider various scenarios that you may come across later on. Do go through the comments once.

Comment: hey man. read the comments plz. it's not a good idea to parse phone numbers as int or long.

Comment: The comments do mention that, but right now the OP has not mentioned them. His title mentions "How to parse 10 digit phone number into Integer in Java" and even his question is directed at that.

Comment: I agree that he might need to work out the logic again for better coverage of cases, but thats for him to work on. I am just helping him with his `error` and clarifying what he can do to avoid it.

Comment: This answer doesn't address leading zeros in the numbers